# eliminar elementos de una lista

Tags: c

Estoy intentando (ya de varias maneras sin conseguirlo aun) restar elementos de una lista, si tengo una lista que contiene [a,b,c,a,a,d,x,z] y por teclado trato de restar elementos que están presentes en dicha lista, no importa el orden de búsqueda en dicha lista y también conservar los repetidos que sobran.

Lejos aun de conseguirlo he logrado eliminar de izquierda a derecha, también que puedan estar salteados los elementos, pero no en desorden (seria genial) o de derecha a izquierda, ya que solo de esta ultima manera logro eliminar el ultimo elemento solamente, alguna ayuda sera muy apreciada, llevo dias en este dilema, he bajado manuales pdf, guias y sigo sin darle al asunto.
Adjunto lo que estoy intentando lograr y también el código que logrado hasta ahora.
Gracias de ante mano.

```
/*
Ejemplo: 

a = [a,b,c,a,a,d,x,z];
b = [x,a,c,z,d];
a - b = [b,a,a]
*/

//Codigo hasta ahora:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

char a[100],b[50];
int j=0,k;
printf("Ingrese Cadena: ");
gets(a);
printf("Caracteres a eliminar: ");
gets(b);
for(int i=0;i<=strlen(a);i++)
{
    while(a[i]==b[j]&&b[j]!='\0')
    {
        for(k=i;a[k]!='\0';k++){
            a[k]=a[k+1];
        }
        j++;
    }
}
    printf("Luego de eliminar:  %s",a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Y no olvides de agregar el código que tengas hecho y detalle el problema de manera explicita.

Comment: muchas gracias por la orientación, espero haber cumplido con las normas, pido disculpas si no es el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta ocasión se me ocurrió cortar la cadena en la posición en donde se encuentra el caracter que se desea eliminar, se hace sobre escribiendo la posición con el caracter fin de cadena '\0' como consecuencia se ha eliminado el caracter pero todos los caracteres después del fin de cadena no son leídos por printf(), entonces para que no se pierdan vuelvo a sobre escribir la posición del caracter eliminado, pero esta vez con el caracter siguiente, y eso se hace con la función strcat() usado para concatenar una cadena con otra, esta operación vendría siendo como un homologo de sumar dos enteros (variable += variable), pero en este caso sumamos dos cadenas de caracteres (string += string).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void eliminarCaracteres(char a[], char caracter){
    for(int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(a[i] == caracter){
            a[i] = '\0';
            strcat(a,&a[i+1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char a[100], b[50];

    printf("Ingrese Cadena: ");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Caracteres a eliminar: ");
    scanf("%s",b);

    for(int i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++){
        eliminarCaracteres(a,b[i]);
    }

    printf("Luego de eliminar:  %s",a);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accimus buenas noches,  a eso me refiero! "sumando dos cadenas de caracteres (string+=string)  es perfecto!